# How to calculate the period of a sequence a [n]?

Tags: differential-equations

The sequence a [n] satisfies this relationship:

```
a[1] == 3, a[n] == 1 - 1/a[n - 1]
```

How to Calculate the Period of a Sequence  `3`

This formula can only calculate the common terms of a sequence of numbers

[image]

```
In[57]:= Clear["Global`*"]
RSolve[{a[1] == 3, a[n] == 1 - 1/a[n - 1]}, a[n], n] // FullSimplify

Out[58]= {{a[n] -> -(1/2) + 7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[(2 n \[Pi])/3])}}

In[61]:= FunctionPeriod[-(1/2) + 7/(
  4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[(2 n \[Pi])/3]), n, Integers]

Out[61]= 3
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question -- you use the symbol T, but this appears no where in your code. If you mean the period of the a[n] sequence, this would be the period of of Cot[ ]. Since this has argument 2 n Pi/3, the period would be 3.

Comment: In mathematical research, the period of function problems or sequence problems is represented by T by default

Comment: MultiplySides[eqn,Times@@Denominator/@eqn,Assumptions->eqn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 13.2 on Widows 10

```
FunctionPeriod[1/2+7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[(2 n \[Pi])/3]), n, Integers]
```

> `3`

Compare with

```
FunctionPeriod[1/2 + 7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[(2 n )/3]), n, Integers]
```

> `0`

Answer (score 3):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {a[1] == 3, a[n] == 1 - 1/a[n - 1]};

sol = RSolveValue[eqns, a[n], n] // FullSimplify

(* -(1/2) + 7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[(2 n π)/3]) *)

eqns /. a[m_] :> (sol /. n -> m) // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)
```

If you were to use the recurrence equations to write a recursive definition for the function then the definition would be restricted to integers. However, in general the result from `RSolve` does not require the arguments to be integers. Consequently, the [`FunctionPeriod`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionPeriod.html) is

```
FunctionPeriod[sol, n]

(* 3/2 *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[sol, {n, 0, 6},
 GridLines -> {Range[0, 6, 3/2], None},
 GridLinesStyle -> {{Red, Dashed, AbsoluteThickness[1]}, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: You wrote "However, in general the result from `RSolve` does not require the arguments to be integers". Think of `RSolve[{a[n + 1] - a[n] == Floor[n], a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]` which results in `{{a[n] -> 1/2 (2 - n + n^2)}}` and `1/2 (2 - n + n^2) /. n -> 1.3` which performs `1.195` and `1/2 (2 - n + n^2) /. n -> 0.3` which produces `0.895`. Therefore, the formula is not valid for `n==0.3`.

Comment: Yes, by injecting an integer function into the recurrence equation you have restricted it to only integer values. However, in American English "generally" means (Merriam-Webster) "in disregard of specific instances and with regard to an overall picture".

Comment: BobHanlon (@ does not work.): You are not right in view of `Floor[0.3]` which results in `0`. BTW, the `Floor` function is defined even for complex values of its argument.

Comment: Re "(@ does not work.)": I have seen this remark multiple times, but only from one poster. It works for all others apparently. And from notifications I've received from said poster (when the @ is used),it seems this claim is simply erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
1/2 + 7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[2 n Pi/3])
```

depends on Cot, which has a period of Pi. Therefore, the argument of Cot must be a multiple of Pi:

```
Solve[2 n Pi/3 == 2 m Pi, n]

{{n -> 3 m}}
```

Therefore, each time if n is a multiple of 3 we get the same value. The period is 3:

```
f[n_] = 1/2 + 7/(4 + 2 Sqrt[3] Cot[2 n Pi/3]);
ListPlot[Table[f[n], {n, 1, 10, 1}]]
```

[image]